# Error message not showing when changes made in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a Codeigniter v3.1.10 project and its working fine. However, when I make any modification externally in the URL like adding any special character (', !, =) etc. at the end of the URL then I'm expecting CI to show the error message like

```
An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters
```

But, instead, it throws an Exception

[image]

In the config.php I have

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Comment: show us your `URL`

Comment: The URL looks like (http://abc.in/sun/cat/browse'). Note the apostrophe at the end of URL

Comment: CI is known for its clean URL and you are challenging it. why?

Comment: A web security company is doing a security audit of my website and they are testing it that way. One more thing......I have another website where if i make any similar changes in the URL then its showing me the Legitimate error message

Comment: A solution can be, You can change the environment from development to production. Then it will show a blank page, if anything goes wrong with url.